# Uploading Image Using FormPanel

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

i am trying to upload image to App Engine Using GWT 
it work fine on localhost ( Using Blob ).

but after Uploading it to App Engine It doesn't work.

i need help, if you have any idea about what is the problem ??????

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not an error message, nor a stacktrace, nor any other piece of information that anyone could use to actually help you.

Comment: try to more specific.. show us your error trace or your code. so that we can help you out

Comment: i traced my code and found that the error in the returned result from server . and i solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i traced my code and found that the error in the returned result from server . and i solved it